# AppFabric caching session state : access session in a WCF app

Tags: wcf, appfabric

I'm working on a project with a web application who call wcf services.
I've decided to use AppFabric Caching for the session state.
I wanted to know if it's possible to access the content of a session with the sessionID in my WCF application ?

Edit : I've decided to stop trying to access session data from WCF. Thx to folks that explained me that is not SOA :)